# How do I keep nested children (li) inline for my footer navigation?

Tags: css, list, navigation, nested, footer

I have a simple question. I'm trying to display the

elements for "about" "general" and "social-buttons" classes within a nested unordered list. I want these to appear horizontal and inline with each other. I want them to be side by side basically, not vertical. If you can help me figure out which selector I need to add the 'display:inline' block, that would be much useful.

```
<div class="footer-container">
<div id="footer_menu">
<div id="footer-copy">
    <li class="about-blurb">
        <h3>Viral DNA</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
            <p>Virael Marketing is the leading digital marketing blog for the social web. We are a one-stop hub to help you learn from your viral marketing campaigns, offer tips & tricks, and build the best digital marketing teams.</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
          <li class="General">
    <h3>General</h3>
         <ul>
        <li><a class="button" href="#">Media</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" href="#">Resources</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a class="button" href="#">Store</a></li>
            <li><a class="button" href="#">Contact</a></li>
             </ul>
    <li class="social-icons">
    <h3>Follow Virael</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
            <!--social media buttons go here--> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.footer-container {
font-family: MyriadPro-Regular, 'Myriad Pro Regular', MyriadPro,'MyriadPro', Arial,  sans-serif;
float: left;
text-align: left;
width: 828px;   
text-transform: capitalize;
background-color: #4169E1;
color: #FFF;
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
left: 269px;
border-top: 10px solid #B0C4DE; 
overflow: hidden;
z-index=-1000;
```

}

```
.footer-container h3 {
text-align:justify;
```

}

```
#footer_menu {
font-family: MyriadPro-Regular, 'Myriad Pro Regular', MyriadPro,'MyriadPro', Arial, sans-serif;
list-style-type:none;
z-index=-1000;
```

}

```
#footer_menu ul {
margin: 0px 30px;
padding: 10px 30px;
list-style-type:none;
text-decoration:none;
display:inline; 
z-index=-1000;
```

}

```
#footer_menu ul li {
margin: 0 0;
padding: 5px 0;
z-index=-100;
display:block;
color: white;
clear:both;
```

}

```
#footer_menu .about-blurb ul li {
width: 200px;
height: auto;
text-align:justify;
```

}

Comment: Could you put this in a fiddle please?

Comment: It also appears you have a lot of unclosed li's....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7xuLR/

Comment: Notice how the three sections are stacked one on top of each other, I want them to line up horizontal or inline

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7xuLR/1/   like this?

Comment: @Mark, maybe I phrased it incorrectly. I want sections "General" and "Social Buttons" to be their own columns...does that make sense?

Comment: Why not just make the there own list? Why nest them?\

Comment: I figured there was a way to do display:inline for children of lists like in horizontal nav bars...

Answer (score 0):

Replace your css with mine. Live example **[here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/0yqcbi1r)**

```
#footer_menu ul {
/* margin: 0px 30px; */
padding: 10px 30px;
list-style-type: none;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline;
}

#footer_menu ul li {
margin: 0 0;
padding: 5px 0;
display: inline-block;
color: white;
clear: both;
}
```

Remove margins from the `ul` and add `inline-block` to `li`

Comment: @user3769350 Can you check the live example? It is working there

Comment: No this is not what I want. I want "General" and "Social Buttons" to be like column 2 and column 3. I'm trying to do this with nested lists as opposed to a table.

Comment: @user3769350 and where are the Social buttons?

Comment: For now, its going to be empty, we can just put some dummy text in it. basically like a twitter follow us icon

Comment: @user3769350 yes, fix your HTML

Comment: Do you mean its better to keep the three sections separate? (make them each their own divs?